# What are the finite order elements of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: group-theory, proof-writing, divisible-groups

I need to find what are the at the group $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$.
I think that any element at this group has a finite order, but I don't know how to prove it... I'd like to get help with the proof writing...

If I'm wrong, I'd like to to know it too...

BTW:
$\mathbb{Z}=(\mathbb{Z},+)$
$\mathbb{Q}=(\mathbb{Q},+)$

Thank you!

Comment: This is a nice example that shows the existence of an infinite group in which every element has a finite order :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you're correct that this is a group in which every element has finite order. Since you've asked about proof writing, I'll write out essentially a full proof.

---

Choose some $\alpha \in \Bbb{Q} / \Bbb{Z}$. By definition of the quotient group, there is a rational number $r$ for which

$$\alpha = r + \mathbb{Z}$$

Now by the definition of $\mathbb{Q}$, there are integers $a$ and $b \ne 0$ (we take $b > 0$) without any loss of generality) for which

$$r = \frac a b \implies \alpha = \frac a b + \mathbb{Z}$$

Therefore,

$$b\alpha = b\left(\frac a b + \Bbb Z\right) = b \frac a b + \Bbb{Z} = a + \Bbb{Z}$$

But since $a$ is an integer, $a + \Bbb{Z} = \Bbb{Z}$ is the identity in $\Bbb{Q} / \Bbb{Z}$, so $\alpha$ has finite order (in fact, the order is at most $b$) as desired.

Answer (score 4):

Each element of $G=(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z},+)$ is of finite order.

$x\in G$, Then $x={p\over q}+\mathbb{Z}, p\in\mathbb{Z},q\in\mathbb{N}$

what is $qx$ then?

$qx=({p\over q}+\mathbb{Z})+({p\over q}+\mathbb{Z})+\dots$ $q$ times$=p+\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 4):

If you know the nature of [Prüfer group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_group) then you may use this [fact](http://people.brandeis.edu/~igusa/Math101b/divisible.pdf) that:

$$\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z=\sum_p\mathbb Z(p^{\infty})$$
However @T.Bongers's post makes the problem easy to understand step by step. Also, it is good to know that, the Prüfer group is an infinite $p-$primary group whose every subgroups if finite and indeed cyclic.

Comment: I start my morning visiting my friends! +1

Comment: @amwhy: it is so early my friend :-)

Comment: It is 6:00 am, my time. Not super early, but early! ;-)

Comment: My current goal is to earn a gold star in abstract algebra and group theory, though elementary set theory is "up there" too. I did earn a gold star (1000 upvotes) in logic most recently! I see your "top" badge (>750 upvotes) is in "group theory". Good for you! We'll get you to gold, yet!!

Comment: Thanks for your sweet words. I hope so. I'll do whatever I can for you. :-))

Comment: And I for you, dear friend! You deserve "Gold for Groups"!! ;-)